# New with Svelte and using Google Places Autocomplete API

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I'm really new with Svelte and I'm trying to make a web component that calls the places autocomplete library of Google. I made it to load the library on my Svelte component, but when I want to pass the autocomplete function to my input it show me the error: InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement.

This is what I tried so far:

```
<svelte:head>
  <script
    defer
    async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDaZc7Jr7pDoK3TWcDiv-SjqiJ0iKz15Go&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
  </script>

  <script>
    function initMap() {
      const input = document.getElementById("autocomplete");
      const options = {
        componentRestrictions: { country: "us" },
        fields: ["address_components", "geometry", "icon", "name"],
        strictBounds: false,
        types: ["establishment"],
      };
      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    }
  </script>
</svelte:head>
```

This is how my input looks like:

```
 <input
    type="text"
    id="autocomplete"
    name="store"
    class="pac-target-input"
    value=""
  />
```

Comment: In which file is your `input` component? I suspect that it isn't initialized/render yet when Google tries to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your input hasn't been rendered to the DOM when you call the `initMap()` method, therefore your `input` variable is null. Svelte offers a `onMount` handler which runs after the component is first rendered to the DOM.
Inside this handler, you can call your `initMap()` function:

```
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

onMount(() => {
    initMap();
});
```

More details: [Svelte Docs](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount)

Answer (score 0):

For me the following was the key in the same component:

**1)**

```
onMount(() => {
    window.initMap = initMap;
});
```

**2)**
Thereafter a regular function in the component block:

```
function initMap() 
{
   const input = document.getElementById("autocomplete");
   const options = ........
}
```